# find list item that exist in another list

Tags: c#, list

I have class department and class employee. Class employee have prop list of departments. If employee contains for example 2 departments i want to find that departments in list of departments that contains all of departments and do something only with them.

```
        List<Department> list = new List<Department>();

        list.Add(new Department() { ID = 101, Name = "IT" });
        list.Add(new Department() { ID = 101, Name = "HR" });
        list.Add(new Department() { ID = 101, Name = "PR" });
        list.Add(new Department() { ID = 101, Name = "Payrol" });


        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.ID = 1;
        employee.Name = "John";
        employee.Gender = "Male";

        employee.Departments = new List<Department>();
        employee.Departments.Add(new Department() { ID = 101, Name = "IT" });
        employee.Departments.Add(new Department() { ID = 101, Name = "HR" });

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            //cannot use Contains because it is checking reference
            if (employee.Departments.Any(d => d.ID == list[i].ID))
                //i want to do something only with items that employee have :-( but this text will be added to all items
                list[i].Name += " employee have this list item";
        }
```

Comment: `if (! employee.Departments.Except(list).Any()) {/* all employee.Departments are in list  */}`

Comment: @fubo OP has explicitly stated that he cannot use `Contains()` because it checks the reference and not the value. And overriding the `Equals()` Method can lead to confusion because one type now works differently from all others

Answer (score 0):

Providing that `Department` class implements `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods you can try *Linq*

If you want to ensure that all departments of `employee` are witin `list` you can try `Except` (there no any department which is in `employee.Departments` but not in `list`):

```
 if (! employee.Departments.Except(list).Any()) {
   // All Departments of employee are within list
 }
```

If you want to find `Department`s which are in *both* lists use `Intersect`:

```
 var inBoth = employee
   .Departments   
   .Intersect(list);

 foreach (var depart in inBoth)
   depart.Name += " employee have this list item";
```

Comment: Thanks. I want simpler solution. My employee have at least 1 department. I simple want to find exactly that departments in all departments and do something with them